# How to properly connect shielded twisted pair cables for Ethernet use?

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable

Some time ago I was in a hotel and they gave me what to me looked like S/STP cable to connect my laptop to their router. What caught my attention was that at both ends of the cable, the shielding just dangled off after the connectors.

That got me thinking: What is used to properly terminate STP cables when they are used for Ethernet?       I know from Wikipedia articles that STP is used for Ethernet in noisy environments, but I was unable to find any more information and I've never seen anything that looks like 8P8C jack which would work with STP cables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Shielded plugs](http://www.vpi.us/installation/assemble-cat6shld.html) have a metal jacket and look like this:

[image: Shielded Plug]

Installation instructions are found at the link above.

Also, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/143436/shielded-ethernet-cable-and-ethernet-sockets-earthing-how-to).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how this works with plastic insides of Ethernet plugs?

Answer (score 2):

go here , it says STP Cables can have RJ45 pins, read under the STP cable article
 http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=31276

Have a look at this presentation (please download this first)

http://www.ethernetip.de/downloads/files/Installation%20of%20Ethernet%20Cables.ppt

here is some information http://www.ampnetconnect.com/documents/Grounding%20and%20Bonding%20_Summary%20-%20pdf%20format.pdf

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any sources which discuss grounding for the shields?

Comment: The download link is: www.ethernetip.de/downloads/files/Installation of Ethernet Cables.ppt